# No Connection String Named "Inventory_ManagementEntities" Could be Found in App.Config file"

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, entity-framework

I am facing this error while opening my application main page designer. Where as in app.config file i can see the entity named "Inventory_ManagementEntities".
[Issue Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhCep.png)

Here is my code of app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Inventory_ManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Base_Table.csdl|res://*/Base_Table.ssdl|res://*/Base_Table.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MOHSINALVI\TESTSERVER;initial catalog=Inventory_Management;user id=sa;password=telco_123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have functions that you have configured and finally not used
To permanently delete them you need to access to link see down **Show Call Stack**
and to delete the function.
[image: show link error]